# Dismiss button (X) on an image - top right alignment HOW?

Tags: swiftui

What is an effective & effecient way to get the Dismiss button (X) into the top right corner?

I'm struggling with container alignment... can't say I GROK it.

Needless to say ... this ain't it!

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Biz-card_2020")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack() {
                    Spacer(minLength: 5)    // vertical space
                    HStack() {
                        Spacer()
                        // close Welcome page (X) button
                        Button(action: {
                            //print(" - Button to dismiss page \(self.isPresented)")
                            self.isPresented = false  // dismiss the Welcome view
                            //print(" - after action Button to dismiss Welcome page \(self.isPresented)")
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle" )
                                .scaledFont(name: "Georgia", size: Const.titleText)
                                .minimumScaleFactor(0.3)
                                .accentColor(.white)
                                .padding(10)
                        })
                        
                    }
                     Spacer()
                }
                
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove `Spacer(minLength: 5)` and replace it with `padding` for `HStack`.

`Spacer(minLength: 5)` doesn't mean its length will be exactly 5 (only that the *minimum* length will be 5).

You may also want to extract close button to another function for clarity.

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    ...

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("Biz-card_2020")
                .resizable()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            closeButton
        }
    }

    var closeButton: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    ...
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                        .padding(10)
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 5)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked Great!  - and yes the breaking it into a subfunction is nice...

Comment: i had no idea I could create a ... what's the "closeButton" generic name for the thing.... sub function of a View... I guess it's a new variable... but that just sounds too.... objecty

Comment: Thats really not a good way to do it, you should use the alignment parameter for ZStack

Answer (score 2):

`ZStack` can be configured using `.topTrailing` etc. You should use those alignments to configure your view. Using something like `Spacer()` is going to cause the rest of your views to get pushed down.

```
 ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
     // your code here
 }
```

If you need to move your code a bit more, use either padding, or offset modifiers.